# problem on UITouchs , after touching the out side of the textfield i.e in view key board should disappear

Tags: iphone

First time the below code works fine ,,,
but after getting back to same view it not working

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    [userNameField resignFirstResponder];
    [passwordField resignFirstResponder];
    [self.view resignFirstResponder];
}
```

this method is not calling after get back to same view , which i have return this code ...
and my problem after touching out side of the textfield i.e on UIView the keyboard show resignFirstReponder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try below code

```
- (IBAction)backgroundTap:(id)sender 
{ 
     [yourtextfield resignFirstResponder];
}
```

In XIB attach this method with **TouchDown** event of **UIView**.

Answer (score 0):

Try with removing below from `touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event`.

```
[self.view resignFirstResponder];
```

[Form Documentation :](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIResponder_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIResponder/resignFirstResponder)

> Notifies the receiver that it has been
>   asked to relinquish its status as
>   first responder in its window.